# TYPO3 9.5.2 / Typoscript: sys_language_mode = content_fallback not working

Tags: typo3, typoscript, slug, typo3-9.x

I added another language en to my homepage and added it also to the sites with entry point /en/. When I translate the startpage and switching the language to en, then it's working fine. But when I click at another page with no translation for en like /en/contact.html, then I got a 404 PageNotFound Exception. My ts config of the page:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    typeNum = 0
    config {
        absRefPrefix = /
        no_cache = 1
        noPageTitle = 1
        linkVars = L(0-10)
        language = de
        locale_all = German
        htmlTag_langKey = de-DE
        sys_language_uid = 0
        sys_language_mode = content_fallback
        sys_language_overlay = 1
}

[globalVar = GP:L=1]
page.config {
    sys_language_uid = 1
}
[global]
```

my sites config:

```
rootPageId: 2
base: 'http://some-domain.de/'
baseVariants: {  }
languages:
  -
    title: 'Meine tolle Webseite'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    flag: de
  -
    title: 'Andere Sprache'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '1'
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: en
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: en
errorHandling: {  }
routes: {  }
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: .html
    map:
      .html: 0
```

Comment: You asked this question twice? :D
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763611/typo3-9-5-2-slug-multilanguage-page-not-found-404-exception-if-no-translation

Comment: No, I think there are two different, but similar problems. One problem is 404 page not found and the other one is, that the content (not page) fallback is not working. For the content fallback I found a bugfix already.

Answer (score 1):

A patch was finally merged: https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/60367
But after release of TYPO3 9.5.5. So expect it to be part of 9.5.6 then.